# Problem with JpaRepository - SQLException: Invalid column name

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot, hibernate

i have problem with my spring proyect using JpaRepository with a custom query and I don't know what is failing.

Mensaje.java class

```
@Entity
public class Mensaje implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    private int ID;

    private String idCampaign;

    private String platform;

    private String deviceID;

    private String lineNumber;
    
    
    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }
    public void setID(int iD) {
        ID = iD;
    }
    public String getIdCampaign() {
        return idCampaign;
    }
    public void setIdCampaign(String idCampaign) {
        this.idCampaign = idCampaign;
    }
    public String getPlatform() {
        return platform;
    }
    public void setPlatform(String platform) {
        this.platform = platform;
    }
    public String getDeviceID() {
        return deviceID;
    }
    public void setDeviceID(String deviceID) {
        this.deviceID = deviceID;
    }
    public String getLineNumber() {
        return lineNumber;
    }
    public void setLineNumber(String lineNumber) {
        this.lineNumber = lineNumber;
    }
    public Mensaje(int iD, String idCampaign, String platform, String deviceID, String lineNumber) {
        super();
        ID = iD;
        this.idCampaign = idCampaign;
        this.platform = platform;
        this.deviceID = deviceID;
        this.lineNumber = lineNumber;
    }
    
    public Mensaje() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    
    
}
```

The service implement

```
    @Override
    public String procesarCampaign(String Idcampaign) {
        List<Mensaje> filas = new ArrayList<>(); 
        filas = gestionBaseDeDatos.buscarCampaign(Idcampaign);
        System.out.println("Registros recuperados: "+filas.size());
        for(int i=0; i<filas.size(); i++) {
            Mensaje aux = filas.get(i);
            producer.sendMessageColaPrincipal(aux);
        }
        return "Procesados "+filas.size()+"mensajes";
                
    }
```

jpaRepositiry interface

```
@Repository
public interface GestionBBDD extends JpaRepository<Mensaje, Long>{
    
    @Query(value="select * from CAMPAIGN where IDCAMPAIGN = "+":idCampaign", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Mensaje> buscarCampaign(@Param("idCampaign")String idCampaign);
    

}
```

Oracle table

```
CREATE TABLE CAMPAIGN(


    ID integer not null,
    idCampaign VARCHAR2(10),
    platform VARCHAR2(1),
    deviceID VARCHAR2(10),
    lineNumber VARCHAR2(9),
        
    CONSTRAINT PK_CAMPAIGN PRIMARY KEY (ID) 

);
```

application.properties

```
# Oracle settings
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.17.0.3:1521:xe
spring.datasource.username=system
spring.datasource.password=oracle
hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
hibernate.show_sql=true
#spring.datasource.driver-class-oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
## Hibernate Properties
# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect

# logging
logging.pattern.console=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
```

the problem is that I always get the same error message, where can the problem be?

the log with the error:

```
2020-12-02 08:49:34 DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - select * from CAMPAIGN

2020-12-02 08:49:34 WARN o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 17006, SQLState: 99999

2020-12-02 08:49:34 ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Invalid column name

2020-12-02 08:49:34 ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute query; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query] with root cause

java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name

at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getColumnIndexPrimitive(OracleStatement.java:3899)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getColumnIndex(OracleStatement.java:3857)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.findColumn(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:
```

Thanks.

Edited
Full logs

```
. ____ _ __ _ _

/\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __ __ _ \ \ \ \

( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \

\\/ ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| | ) ) ) )

' |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /

=========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/

:: Spring Boot :: (v2.4.0)


2020-12-02 11:49:18 INFO c.t.ajpn.GestionColasApplication - Starting GestionColasApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 1.8.0_212 on 1ef21643a295 with PID 1 (/gestionColas.jar started by spring in /)

2020-12-02 11:49:18 INFO c.t.ajpn.GestionColasApplication - No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default

2020-12-02 11:49:21 INFO o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFERRED mode.

2020-12-02 11:49:21 INFO o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 170 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.

2020-12-02 11:49:23 INFO o.s.b.w.e.tomcat.TomcatWebServer - Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8181 (http)

2020-12-02 11:49:23 INFO o.a.catalina.core.StandardService - Starting service [Tomcat]

2020-12-02 11:49:23 INFO o.a.catalina.core.StandardEngine - Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.39]

2020-12-02 11:49:23 INFO o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext

2020-12-02 11:49:23 INFO o.s.b.w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4562 ms

2020-12-02 11:49:23 INFO o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor - Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'

2020-12-02 11:49:23 INFO o.h.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]

2020-12-02 11:49:24 INFO org.hibernate.Version - HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.23.Final

2020-12-02 11:49:24 WARN o.s.b.a.o.j.JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration - spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning

2020-12-02 11:49:24 INFO o.h.annotations.common.Version - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}

2020-12-02 11:49:24 INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Starting...

2020-12-02 11:49:25 INFO o.s.b.w.e.tomcat.TomcatWebServer - Tomcat started on port(s): 8181 (http) with context path ''

2020-12-02 11:49:25 INFO o.s.d.r.c.DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener - Triggering deferred initialization of Spring Data repositories…

2020-12-02 11:49:26 INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Start completed.

2020-12-02 11:49:26 INFO org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect

2020-12-02 11:49:30 INFO o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator - HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]

2020-12-02 11:49:30 INFO o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'

2020-12-02 11:49:32 INFO o.s.d.r.c.DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener - Spring Data repositories initialized!

2020-12-02 11:49:32 INFO c.t.ajpn.GestionColasApplication - Started GestionColasApplication in 16.484 seconds (JVM running for 18.063)

2020-12-02 11:49:38 INFO o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'

2020-12-02 11:49:38 INFO o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'

2020-12-02 11:49:38 INFO o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Completed initialization in 7 ms

2020-12-02 11:49:39 DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - select mensaje0_.id as id1_0_, mensaje0_.deviceid as deviceid2_0_, mensaje0_.id_campaign as id_campaign3_0_, mensaje0_.line_number as line_number4_0_, mensaje0_.platform as platform5_0_ from campaign mensaje0_ where mensaje0_.id_campaign=?

2020-12-02 11:49:39 WARN o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 904, SQLState: 42000

2020-12-02 11:49:39 ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ORA-00904: "MENSAJE0_"."ID_CAMPAIGN": invalid identifier


2020-12-02 11:49:39 ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause

oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-00904: "MENSAJE0_"."ID_CAMPAIGN": invalid identifier


at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:513)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:461)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1104)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:553)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:269)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:655)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:270)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:91)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:807)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:983)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1168)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3666)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeInternal(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1426)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3713)

at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1167)

at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)

at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)

at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57)

at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2304)

at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2057)

at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2019)

at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:948)

at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349)

at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2850)

at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2832)

at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2664)

at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2659)

at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506)

at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:400)

at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219)

at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1414)

at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1565)

at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1533)

at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165)

at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:126)

at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:88)

at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:155)

at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:143)

at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)

at org.springframework.dat

a.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)

at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:152)

at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:131)

at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)

at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)

at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)

at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:371)

at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:134)

at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)

at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)

at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)

at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:145)

at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)

at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)

at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)

at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)

at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy90.buscarCampaign(Unknown Source)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)

at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)

at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy64.buscarCampaign(Unknown Source)

at com.telefonica.ajpn.service.impl.ColaServiceImpl.procesarCampaign(ColaServiceImpl.java:40)

at com.telefonica.ajpn.controller.ColaController.procesarCampaign(ColaController.java:27)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197)

at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:893)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:807)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1061)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:961)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)

at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)

at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)

at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)

at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)

at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)

at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)

at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)

at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)

at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)

at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)

at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)

at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)

at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)

at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)

at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)

at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)

at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)

at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Why are you working around JPA and Spring Data JPA? DItch the finder method with the query and add `findByIdCampaign(String idCampaign)` and Spring Data will generate the query for you.

Comment: Hi, I am new to JPA and I do not know what the difference is between JPA and Spring Data JPA, I have done the construction through examples on iternet.

Comment: If you write the Select statement with explicit column names, what is the behavior?

Answer (score 0):

check with below Query:-

```
 @Query(SELECT u FROM CAMPAIGN u WHERE u.IDCAMPAIGN = ?1)
    List<Mensaje> buscarCampaign(@Param("idCampaign")String idCampaign);
```

make your Query simple:--

```
CREATE TABLE CAMPAIGN(


    ID integer not null,
    id_Campaign VARCHAR2(10),
    platform VARCHAR2(1),
    device_ID VARCHAR2(10),
    line_Number VARCHAR2(9),
        
    PRIMARY KEY (ID) 

);
```

property file :--

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= none // if you want to create manually tbl
```

//pojo Mensaje table name is  CAMPAIGN right?

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CAMPAIGN")        // **you have missed it**
public class Mensaje implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    

//field
//setter
//getter
}
```

Jpa provides you various method but still why you want to use JPQL though it's basic query.

Hope that will resolve your issue.

Comment: I've tried, but in the logs the query is not correct;                                                           
 DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - select mensaje0_.id as id1_0_, mensaje0_.deviceid as deviceid2_0_, mensaje0_.id_campaign as id_campaign3_0_, mensaje0_.line_number as line_number4_0_, mensaje0_.platform as platform5_0_ from campaign mensaje0_ where mensaje0_.id_campaign=?

2020-12-02 11:23:01 WARN o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 904, SQLState: 42000

ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ORA-00904: "MENSAJE0_"."ID_CAMPAIGN": invalid identifier

Comment: post complete log trace

Comment: have you checked table field name? is it the same?

Comment: Try this query : `@Query(value="select * from CAMPAIGN where id_campaign = ?1", nativeQuery = true)` and as function `List<Mensaje> buscarCampaign(String idCampaign);` @FireStarter

Comment: dude check with my answer?

Comment: @priyranjan I have left the logs at the beginning. the @query like you said have a compilation problem "org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: CAMPAIGN is not mapped [SELECT u FROM CAMPAIGN u WHERE u.IDCAMPAIGN = ?1]", I change to "@Query("SELECT u FROM Mensaje u WHERE u.idCampaign = ?1")" and don`t get complitation error but get the error what you can see in the logs. I've see something (
could this be the cause of the problem) the table on oracle call "CAMPAIGN" but the class is named "Mensaje". should they have the same name?.

Comment: yes table name should match. did you see my native sql field name? is this the same r u using?

Comment: @priyranjan the name of the class is the same as the table. i've checked your native sql field name and it's the same, now don't get compilation error, but in the logs is wrong the query `select campaign0_.id as id1_0_, campaign0_.deviceid as deviceid2_0_, campaign0_.id_campaign as id_campaign3_0_, campaign0_.line_number as line_number4_0_, campaign0_.platform as platform5_0_ from campaign campaign0_ where campaign0_.id_campaign=?` . why the query is id1_0 and deviceid2_0?.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

I've made some changes,

Reaname the class Mensaje.java to Campaign.java (the same nafe for the class an the oracle table) and the names of the fields in lowercase.

The query it has been like this

```
@Repository
public interface GestionBBDD extends JpaRepository<Campaign, Long>{
    
    @Query("SELECT u FROM Campaign u WHERE u.campaign = ?1")
    List<Campaign> buscarCampaign(@Param("idCampaign")String idCampaign);

}
```

Thank you all, I am very grateful!